# How to change button text on click using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Only started JS a couple of days ago, and I'm already having some troubles getting a toggle to work. I want the button to toggle between `on` and `off` when clicked.

```js
function click() {
  var change = document.getElementById("toggle");
  if (change.innerHTML == "on"); {
    change.innerHTML = "off";
  } else {
    change.innerHTML = "on";
  }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="toggle" onClick="click()">on</button>
```

Is this how I should go about it?

Comment: Does it work?  If not, what's wrong with it (be precise)?  Do you just want style advice?

Comment: Your if expression should not have a semicolon after `== "on")`

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom it's not working at all unfortunately! I just want to know why that may be. I thought I may be missing something someone could spot out

Comment: If you open your console, you will see a syntax error, most likely on the `else`. Did you open the console? Do you know how to open the console? You should learn that before you do anything else.

Comment: Try pressing F12. A new world of debugging awaits you.

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

        <button id="toggle" onclick="myFunction()">on</button>

        <script>

            function myFunction() {
                var change = document.getElementById("toggle");
                if (change.innerHTML == "on")
                {
                    change.innerHTML = "off";
                }
                else {
                    change.innerHTML = "on";
                }
            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

define your function to be unique as always
and not make use of the javascript function/reserve words
just a recommendation/suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Your having mistake in the if statement,there is no semicolon after if statement
write the code as like below

```
 <button name="toggle" id="toggle" onclick="myFunction()">on</button>

            <script>

                function myFunction() {
                    var change = document.getElementById("toggle");
                    if (change.innerHTML == "on")
                    {
                        change.innerHTML = "off";
                    }
                    else {
                        change.innerHTML = "on";
                    }
                }

            </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
<button type = "button" id= "toggle" onClick = "click()">on</button>


function click()
{
    var change = document.getElementById("toggle");
    if (change.value == "on")
    {
        change.value = "off";
    }
    else 
    {
      change.value = "on";
    }
}
```

or by doing this:

```
function click()
{
    if (this.value=="on")
    {
        this.value = "off";
    }
    else 
    {
         this.value = "on";
    }
}
```

Comment: You've left in the spurious semi-colon after the first `if` statement, which will cause the parser to choke.

Comment: Ah yes right you are - I have corrected it - just a typo!

Answer (score 0):

It will work for you

```
function myFunction()
    {
        var change = document.getElementById("toggle");
        if (change.value=="off") change.value = "on";
        else change.value = "off";
    }
```

for button

```
<input type="button" value="on" id="toggle" onclick="myFunction()">
```